# WordPress: Append Text to Image Caption

Tags: php, wordpress, caption

I am seeking help in appending text to image captions in WordPress. I have tried two different pieces of code without success. The image caption displays normally without the appended text.

I have tried the following:

```
add_filter('img_caption_shortcode', 'modify_caption_text', 10, 3);

function modify_caption_text($output, $attr, $content) {
    $caption = isset($attr['caption']) ? $attr['caption'] : '';
    $new_caption = $caption . ' - Custom Text';
    return str_replace($caption, $new_caption, $output);
}
```

and

```
function append_image_credit_to_caption($output, $attr, $content) {
    // Your additional text
    $additional_text = "<em>Custom Text</em>";

    // Append the additional text to the caption
    $output .= $additional_text;

    return $output;
}
add_filter('img_caption_shortcode', 'append_image_credit_to_caption', 10, 3);
```

As the code above is not returning any errors within WordPress, is there something I am overlooking?

Thank you

Comment: if you use `get_the_content` - it doesn't `apply filters`. Use  `the_content()` or change it to something like this

Comment: Hello Denis, thanks for your help. Where have I used "get_the_content"?

Comment: most likely in the file `single.php ` or `page.php`, the type of content that contains images with captions

Comment: Hi Denis, it still isn't working for me. Shouldn't one of the above code snippets work given that the image caption function is being called as per the WordPress documentation?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this hook only applies for images you output via the `[caption]` shortcode, https://codex.wordpress.org/Caption_Shortcode - is that actually your scenario here?

Comment: your example seems to work, so it is important to make sure that the `apply_filters` are applied when the page is rendered

Comment: could you share the code of the file of the page you want to display?

Comment: Hi CBroe, I think you may be right. Thanks for the pointer.